# d3.event.loaded in d3 version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to show progress bar while data is loading. I've found Mike Bostock’s code:
[progress events](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941) It works but it's written in d3v3 and my code in d3v4, so I want to update it to version v.

So far I've changed `var arc = d3.svg.arc()` into `var arc = d3.arc()` but I'm stuck on `d3.event.loaded`, console shows: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of null`.

How I can change update it?

Comment: Could you post your sample code in the form of a fiddle / block for us to take a look. It might be easier to see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `d3.event` is `null`. You can do something like the following code just use `.loaded`. There are better ways to do this but just using your example the following should work.

```
d3.json("https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/git/blobs/2e0e3b6305fa10c1a89d1dfd6478b1fe7bc19c1e?" + Math.random())
.on("progress", function (d) {
    console.log(d.loaded)
    var i = d3.interpolate(progress, d.loaded / total);
    d3.transition().tween("progress", function () {
        return function (t) {
            progress = i(t);
            foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
            text.text(formatPercent(progress));
        };
    });
})
.get(function (error, data) {
    meter.transition().delay(250).attr("transform", "scale(0)");
});
```